# How to reduce constrained HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

How to fix the code below so it works?

```
object Foo {
  object sum extends Poly {
    implicit def caseFoo = use((f1: Int, f2: Int) => f1 + f2)
  }

  def foo[L <: HList : <<:[Int]#λ](l: L): Int = {
    l.reduceLeft(sum)
    // Error: could not find implicit value for parameter reducer: shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftReducer[L,com.struct.Foo.sum.type] 
    //   l.reduceLeft(sum)
    // Error: not enough arguments for method reduceLeft: (implicit reducer: shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftReducer[L,com.struct.Foo.sum.type])reducer.Out. 
    //   Unspecified value parameter reducer.
  }
}
```

Additionally. How to change it so it reduces HList of any Numerics?

**Update:**

Please consider fuller example of my problem:

```
import shapeless._

trait Bar {
  def foo: Int
}
case class Foo[L <: HList](l: L) extends Bar {
  object sum extends Poly {
    implicit def caseFoo[A: Numeric] = use((f1: A, f2: A) => f1 + f2)
    //Error: type mismatch;
    //found   : A
    //required: String
  }
  override def foo(implicit reducer: LeftReducer[L, sum.type]): Int = reducer(l)
  //Error: type mismatch;
  //found   : reducer.Out
  //required: Int
}
```

**Update:**

```
package com.test

import shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftReducer
import shapeless.{HList, HNil, Poly}

trait Bar {
  def foo: Int
}

case class Foo[L <: HList](list: L) extends Bar {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  object sum extends Poly {
    implicit def caseFoo[A: Numeric] = use((f1: A, f2: A) => f1 + f2)
  }

  class MkFoo[T] {
    def apply(l: L)(implicit reducer: LeftReducer.Aux[L, sum.type, T]): T = reducer(l)
  }

  override def foo: Int = (new MkFoo[Int]())(list)
  // Error: could not find implicit value for parameter reducer: shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftReducer.Aux[L,Foo.this.sum.type,Int]

}

object Testing {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val b:Bar  = Foo(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil)
    println(b.foo)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works:**

```
package com.test

import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil, Lazy}


trait Bar {
  def foo: Int
}

case class Foo[L <: HList](list: L)(implicit ev: SizeCalculator[L]) extends Bar {
  override def foo: Int = ev.size(list)
}

object Testing {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val b: Bar = Foo(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil)
    println(b.foo)
  }
}


sealed trait SizeCalculator[T] {
  def size(value: T): Int
}

object SizeCalculator {

  // "Summoner" method
  def apply[A](implicit enc: SizeCalculator[A]): SizeCalculator[A] = enc

  // "Constructor" method
  def instance[A](func: A => Int): SizeCalculator[A] = new SizeCalculator[A] {
    def size(value: A): Int = func(value)
  }

  import Numeric.Implicits._

  implicit def numericEncoder[A: Numeric]: SizeCalculator[A] = new SizeCalculator[A] {
    override def size(value: A): Int = value.toInt()
  }

  implicit def hnilEncoder: SizeCalculator[HNil] = instance(hnil => 0)

  implicit def hlistEncoder[H, T <: HList](
                                            implicit
                                            hInstance: Lazy[SizeCalculator[H]],
                                            tInstance: SizeCalculator[T]
                                          ): SizeCalculator[H :: T] = instance {
    case h :: t =>
      hInstance.value.size(h) + tInstance.size(t)
  }

  implicit def genericInstance[A, R](
                                      implicit
                                      generic: Generic.Aux[A, R],
                                      rInstance: Lazy[SizeCalculator[R]]
                                    ): SizeCalculator[A] = instance { value => rInstance.value.size(generic.to(value)) }


  def computeSize[A](value: A)(implicit enc: SizeCalculator[A]): Int = enc.size(value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `LUBConstraint.<<:` type is unconstructive in sense that it could only be evident that all `HList` members have some type, but can not derive anything from it.

To use `reduceLeft` method you need specifically `LeftReducer` operation provider. You can require it in your method directly.

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist._

object Foo {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  object sum extends Poly {
    implicit def caseFoo[A: Numeric] = use((f1: A, f2: A) => f1 + f2)
  }

  def foo[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit reducer: LeftReducer[L, sum.type]): reducer.Out = 
    reducer(l)
}


Foo.foo(1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil) // res0: Int = 6

Foo.foo(1.0 :: 2.0 :: 3.0 :: HNil) // res1: Double = 6.0
```

#### Update

If you need direct evidence, that your result will be of some result type you can use additional type argument, but that needs separation of type parameters via the **Typed Maker** pattern

```
object Foo {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  object sum extends Poly {
    implicit def caseFoo[A: Numeric] = use((f1: A, f2: A) => f1 + f2)
  }

  def foo[T] = new MkFoo[T]

  class MkFoo[T] {
    def apply[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit reducer: LeftReducer.Aux[L, sum.type, T]): T = reducer(l)
  }
}
```

now

```
Foo.foo[Int](1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil)
Foo.foo[Double](1.0 :: 2.0 :: 3.0 :: HNil)
```

will still produce correct result, while

```
Foo.foo[Double](1 :: 2 :: 3 :: HNil)
```

will fail at compile time

Comment: Hi @Odomontis, thanks for the answer. But I have followup questions.
1. f1 + f2 does not work as Numeric has no + defined. Replacing it with 'plus' is no help as probably Numeric needs to be parametrised i guess.
2. in your solution you have changed foo signature. Now instead of returning Int it is declared to return reducer.Out. What if Foo needs to implement a trait which defines 'def foo():Int' and Foo takes [L <: HList] parameter in its constructor?
3. Since foo returns reducer.Out why we see Int as a return value in tests?

Comment: @Lambder, did you include the `Numeric.Implicits._` import?

Comment: @Lambder `Numeric` needs no type parameter, as it used in the [context bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds) position

Comment: Bar.size doesn't take parameter

Comment: ... and Foo should be a case class extending Bar